# wysihtml5 text editor in iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, wysihtml5

I am trying to use a simple implementation of wysihtml5 to be able to perform rich text editing (and store the html directly to be able to save formatting in a standard format).

For this I have implemented wysihtml5 like this

```
<form>
    <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
</form>

<script src="./wysihtml5/parser_rules/simple.js"></script>
<script src="./wysihtml5/dist/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
<script>    
  var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("textarea", {
    parserRules:    wysihtml5ParserRules,
    useLineBreaks:  false
  });
</script>
```

To be able to manipulate it in iOS, I am using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` as

```
- (void) setText:(NSString *)text
{                              
    [self.webView 
        stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString 
                                 stringWithFormat:@"editor.setValue(%@)", text]];
}
- (NSString *)getText
{
    NSString *text = [self.webView 
                    stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"editor.getValue()"];
    return text;
}
```

However, neither the set works nor the get (always returns an empty string).
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)insertHTMLContent:(NSString *)HTMLBody
{
    if (HTMLBody) {
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"editor.composer.commands.exec('insertHTML', '%@')", HTMLBody];
        [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:query];
    }
}

- (NSString *)getContentHtml {
    return [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"editor.getValue()"];
}
```